# Rails handle nil/undefined method

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to move something called /categories all over to /digital-catalog.

I'm having everything redirect over and it works, however it fails when entering in a url_name when it's not present.

I'm pretty much a novice with ternary operator but it looks like it's failing.

The code is failing at the following:

```
- custom_search_path = action_name == 'show' ? category_path(@category.url_name) : digital_catalog_path
.search-cont
 = form_tag custom_search_path, id: 'search-filter', method: :get do
   = search_field_tag :search_input, params[:search_input], placeholder: 'Search', class: 'form-control'
   - if params[:search_input]
     = link_to 'x', custom_search_path, class: 'add-on'
   = submit_tag 'go'
```

The exact error message is:

> NoMethodError in Categories#show
>
> undefined method `url_name' for nil:NilClass

My CategoriesController looks like:

```
class CategoriesController < ApplicationController
  respond_to :html, :json
  before_action :load_category, only: [:show]
  before_action :require_user

  def index
    @categories = Category.ordered.search(params[:search_input]).paginate(page: params[:page])
    respond_with @categories
  end

  def show
    if @category.nil?
      redirect_to '/'
    else
      @items = @items.search(params[:search_input]).paginate(page: params[:page])
      @response = { category: @category, items: @items }
      respond_with @response
    end
  end

  private

  def load_category
    @category = Category.find_by!(url_name: params[:id])
    @items = @category.items
    add_breadcrumb 'categories', digital_catalog_path
    add_breadcrumb @category.name
  end
end
```

How do I handle when someone enters in a url that doesn't match here?

I've tried putting in a helper instead with the following:

```
def route_category
 if action_name == 'show'
   redirect_to digital_catalog_path(@category.url_name)
 else
   redirect_to root_path
 end
end
```

Which ends up with undefined method `redirect_to' and honestly that doesn't solve the issue with the form tag getting the right data.

EDIT:

I have also tried to the same error message:

```
def show
 if @category.url_name.nil?
   redirect_to root_path
 else
   @items = @items.search(params[:search_input]).paginate(page: params[:page])
   @response = { category: @category, items: @items }
   respond_with @response
 end
end
```

So how to I handle a url that isn't present?

EDIT: I've added in the entirety of the CategoriesController. Along with an update on the show method which I thought would handle the error but it doesn't.

Comment: The error message is pretty clear: `@category` is `nil`. Have you called `load_category` before rendering? (maybe in a `before_action` in the controller?)

Comment: There is a before_action :load_category, only: [:show]

Comment: can you post the entirety of your CategoriesController please?

Comment: @Deekor I updated with the entirety of the controller.

Comment: So what exactly is the question? How to render a 404?

Answer (score 0):

I still have yet to find the right method to send it to a 404 page but this is my stopgap:

```
def show
 if @category
   @items = @items.search(params[:search_input]).paginate(page: params[:page])
   @response = { category: @category, items: @items }
   respond_with @response
 else
   redirect_to digital_catalog_path
 end
end

private

def load_category
  begin
    @category = Category.find_by!(url_name: params[:id])
    @items = @category.items
    add_breadcrumb 'categories', digital_catalog_path
    add_breadcrumb @category.name
  rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound => e
    @category = nil
  end
end
```